# Apache2.4 mod_ratelimit not setting proper speeds

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, throttling, bandwidth, rate-limiting

so I was looking for an easy way to setup bandwidth throttling on my website. I installed debian 11, apache2.4, ispconfig, etc. I enabled mod_ratelimit and modified .htaccess to set the limits. Amazingly it worked.. kinda. No matter what I put, max download speed was 121k/s. Disabling it I would get 50mb/sec which is what I normally get on my gigabit connection (only 256mb/up).

```
SetEnv rate-limit 100 = 121kb/sec
SetEnv rate-limit 512 = 121kb/sec
SetEnv rate-limit 25000 = 121kb/sec
```

I only found 1 mention of something similar to this anywhere, and the guy had a similar issue, that it would only do 2 different speeds, 68mb/sec or 178mb/sec and without it he got 300mb/sec.

Similar but not exact, and I cannot figure out how the heck to fix this. The idea was to use this module and set guest users to 400k/sec max, and paid users get 1mb/sec max for tier 1, 5mb/max for tier 2, etc, by set_env variable in php. (not sure that's the right variable name, but you should get what I mean). does anyone else have this issue and is there a way to fix this?

I tried remove burst, since it did not seem to do anything. My download starts at about 10k/sec and slowly climbs to 121k/set then sits there.

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess for that directory increase by 1000 not 100

```
<IfModule ratelimit_module>
SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
SetEnv rate-limit 5000
SetEnv rate-initial-burst 8000
</IfModule>
```